# How can I assign an enum to an attribute with the information of another enum attribute?

Tags: java, enums, interface, attributes, assign

I have 3 different enums which contain values that define a type of element, and then I have an enum which contains values to specify any of those 3 enums

Something like this (this is an example):

```
public enum Vehicles {

    CAR("This is a car"),
    BIKE("This is a bike"),
    TRUCK("This is a truck");

    private String description;
    
    private Vehicles(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

and the other 3 enums are something like this:

```
public enum CAR_ENUM {

    COUPE("This car is a coupe"),
    SEDAN("This car is a sedan");

    private String description;
    
    private CAR_ENUM(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}

public enum BIKE_ENUM {
    
        CHOPPER("This bike is a chopper"),
        SPORTS("This bike is a sports one");
    
        private String description;
        
        private BIKE_ENUM(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
        
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
    }

public enum TRUCK_ENUM {
        
            SMALLTRUCK("This is a small truck"),
            BIGTRUCK("This is a big truck");
        
            private String description;
            
            private TRUCK_ENUM(String description) {
                this.description = description;
            }
            
            public String getDescription() {
                return description;
            }
        }
```

Now, there is a class (lets call it CarDealer) where I need to declare the attributes.
First, I need to declare a Vehicles item and then another attribute that just reads the Vehicles enum and creates an attribute depending on that enum...

So, in practice, it should be something like:

```
public class CarDealer {

    private Vehicles vehicle;
    private (enum that fits whatever value the Vehicles enum has);

}
```

Also, I cannot alter those 3 enums (because they are used somewhere else in the application)

I thought that maybe I could use interfaces or something, but I'm not that experimented, I could totally use some ideas...

Hope you can give me some help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am confused, can you provide a more realistic codebase so that we understand what you really want to achieve? Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias I modified it to give an example that fits my situation, hope it's enough

Comment: If the class is `CarDealer` can't you simply use `private CAR_ENUM carType;`? What do you want to do with these Enums, maybe there is a better way if you could explain exactly the use case you are trying to solve.

Comment: @JoãoDias CarDealer is a Data Transfer Object, and whenever we give the vehicle attribute a value, the idea is that there's an attribute that takes the value of that enum (for example, let's say that vehicle returns the CAR_ENUM, but it could also return a BIKE_ENUM or a TRUCK_ENUM, so the attribute has to be ready to retrieve whichever value it is and make it a different enum depending on the situation... I think there might be a generic way to declare the enum, but I'm a little bit lost). I only need to retrieve database info into those fields.

Comment: Then I would say you need different classes: `Car`, `Bike` and `Truck` and not an enum with all three possibilities. ut to be certain of that we would need to have more context about your use case, because I think we are dealing with a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here.

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced that using enums is appropriate to your situation. But I’ll ignore that, to answer the Question directly.

By the way, an enum should be named in the singular as it is not a collection. So, `enum Vehicle`, not `Vehicles`. I wonder if that mistaken thinking of enums as collections may be at the root of your possible design problem. But, again, I will set that aside to answer directly.

## Ideal solution

Be aware of the classes `EnumSet` and `EnumMap` which are highly efficient implementations of `Set` and `Map` designed for enums. They are fast to execute and take little memory.

Define all the kinds of vehicles in one enum. Nest that enum. Add a collection of these vehicle-kind enum objects to the `Vehicle` enum class. Add a second parameter to the constructor of `Vehicle` to pass the collection of vehicle-kind enum objects.

```java
public enum Vehicle {

    CAR( "This is a car" , EnumSet.of( Vehicle.Variety.COUPE , Vehicle.Variety.SEDAN  ) ),
    BIKE( "This is a bike" , EnumSet.of( Vehicle.Variety.CHOPPER , Vehicle.Variety.SPORTS  ) ),
    TRUCK( "This is a truck" , EnumSet.of( Vehicle.Variety.SMALLTRUCK , Vehicle.Variety.BIGTRUCK  ) );

    public enum Variety {
        COUPE , SEDAN ,         // Cars
        CHOPPER , SPORT ,       // Bikes
        SMALLTRUCK , BIGTRUCK   // Trucks
    }

    private String description;
    private Set< Vehicle.Variety > varieties ;
    
    private Vehicle ( String description , Set< Vehicle.Variety > varieties) {
        this.description = description ;
        this.varieties = varieties ;
    }
    
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description ;
    }

    public Set< Variety > getVarieties() {
        return Set.copyOf( this.varieties ) ;  // Defensive programming, return a copy, not original.
    }

}
```

If your `CarDealer` (`VehicleDealer`?) specializes in bikes, then when you assign `Vehicle.BIKE` object, you indirectly are also providing `CHOPPER` and `SPORTS` via the `getVarieties()` method.

## Practical workaround

You said you already have the three variety enums defined in project, and cannot change them.

But perhaps you can make them implement an interface named `Variety`. The interface would be empty, no behavior (except for a `getDescription` method). But sharing that interface type would allow you to have that `Set < Variety >` member field on `Vehicle`.

Or, given that your predicament is not entirely clear to us, perhaps just use a map. Make an `Map< Vehicle , Set< Variety >` using `EnumMap` and `EnumSet` as the concrete classes.